# Height of word boxes typed with Calibri font on Mac and Windows are different

Tags: html, css, windows, macos, fonts

I have a problem, I cannot solve for several hours. I have a webpage http://skyeng.ru. Here we have a menu typed with Calibri font. And it renders very different on Mac and Windows:  http://monosnap.com/image/BKucFYKjAIP0CotqHgqwIU0ny8lrtO — you can see on Mac height of the box is 20px, but at the same time on Windows — http://monosnap.com/image/FKy8SVuxJHPtzj5Fwe8PTEvGXTfgMK.

- Line height is the same
- Browser is the same (Chrome)
- Anti aliasing mode doesnt change smth
- Font size is the same

Looks like there are rendering process differents, but I have no idea how to solve it.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the general case, you can't. Pixel-perfect rendering across Windows and OS/X is rarely possible (unless you only use images). The font rendering on Mac is very sophisticated (compared to any other OS; a relic of having [NeXT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NeXT) as an ancestor).

Even Safari doesn't render the same on Windows and on Mac. Sometimes, PDF files look different (usually better) on Mac.

A workaround is to size the container with a fixed height but then, you get all the usual problems when zooming and people with disabilities. And let's not get started with people who disable web fonts.